# C# date time Time span

Tags: c#

I want a timespan with a message box that tells which part of the day it is. I have the goodmorning, good first part of the day and good second part of the day. I also have good evening. I am a beginner with C#. Now the code show's all the messageboxes at once (after 1 another). Can someone explain to me what i am doing wrong here.

**This is my code:**

I tried to do it like: if(morgenStart == b && morgenEnd == b)

But that doesn't work either, the expected code needs to show me which part of the day it is with the messagebox.

```
TimeSpan morgenStart = new TimeSpan(06, 0, 0);
TimeSpan morgenEnd = new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0);
TimeSpan middagStart = new TimeSpan(12, 0, 0);
TimeSpan middagEnd = new TimeSpan(14, 0, 0);
TimeSpan namiddagStart = new TimeSpan(17, 0, 0);
TimeSpan namiddagEnd = new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0);

String a = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
TimeSpan b = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

textBox1.Text = a + " " + b;

if (morgenStart < morgenEnd)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Goedemorgen", "Tijd",
   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
if (middagStart < middagEnd)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Goedemiddag", "Tijd",
   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
if (namiddagStart < namiddagEnd)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Goede namiddag", "Tijd",
   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Goede avond", "Tijd",
   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be comparing `b` to you start/end times, rather than comparing your start/end times to each other?

Comment: Look at your first if statement: `morgenStart < morgenEnd`, that is always going to be true. I suspect you want to be comparing with `b`. The same goes for the rest of your comparisons. You should learn how to debug your code, this is fairly simple to step through.

Comment: @Rawling Yes i tried if(morgenStart == b && morgenEnd == b) but that doesn't work either. What should it be?

Comment: Use `if (b > morgenStart && b < morgenEnd)`

Comment: @DavidG Yeah i am a real beginner in this, i love to learn more

Comment: @DavidG I will do that

Comment: @DavidG It works thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statements should be comparing with `b`. Also, consider using `else if` blocks to prevent multiple matches. For example:

```
if (b > morgenStart && b < morgenEnd)
{
    //Goedemorgen
}
else if (b > middagStart && b < middagEnd)
{
    //Goedemiddag
}
else if (b > namiddagStart && b < namiddagEnd)
{
    //Goede namiddag
}
else
{
    //Not really sure what you want to do here, I don't speak Dutch!
    //Goede avond
}
```

Comment: answer is good, just something to add since he's a beginner: Use better variable names than `a` and `b`, I suggest `currentTime` or something like this.

further improvement: instead of writing `MessageBox.Show("Goede namiddag", "Tijd", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);` four times, you can store the message in a string: `string message;` before the if clause, in the if statement you can set the string `message = "Goede namiddag";` and after the if clauses you can open the messagebox: `MessageBox.Show(message, "Tijd", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);`

Comment: That was it, i was so close haha. Thankyou